# java api for comparing MP3 contents?

Tags: java, audio, mp3

I am new to this and I don't know what to do? I want to compare two MP3 files and check whether they are same or different. I want to check it by its content. please help me. I searched everywhere but not getting anything.

Comment: Why does it necessarily need to be an mp3 API, couldn't you just compare the file sizes or would files be different sizes but contain the same song?

Comment: what means `MP3 contents`? ID3? bytecode?

Comment: i want to check whether they contain same song or not

Comment: Comparing audio files is like comparing images, hard. If a single thing changes, like if it is compressed with other setting, re-compressed, byte comparison will will fail. So the best way to do such a thing is to look for something that can do that, and look how you could integrate that into Java. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_fingerprint) for some introduction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Guava Libraries](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

Perform a `crc32` checksum calculation

```
File myfile1 = new File("file1.mp3");
long checksum1 = Files.getChecksum(myfile1 , new java.util.zip.CRC32());

File myfile2 = new File("file2.mp3");
long checksum2 = Files.getChecksum(myfile2 , new java.util.zip.CRC32());

if (checksum1 == checksum2)    {
    System.out.println(" Both are same ");
    // your business logic
}
```

In case you are not satisfied with checksum and want to do  a `sha-256` digest calculation

```
byte[] digest = Files.getDigest(myfile1 , MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256"));
```

Comment: Or calculate the checksum without an additional lib: http://stackoverflow.com/a/304350/1165132

Comment: Original poster clarifies that "i want to check whether they contain same song or not" not if the files are identical, which is what this will do.

Comment: Why not simply compare the files byte-by-byte? They have to be read from disk anyway, so why do all the extra math?

Answer (score 0):

You say "I searched everywhere but not getting anything." If this is true, then you searched for the wrong thing. I just went to google and typed "stack overflow check if two songs are the same" and got these two answers to your question:

[Is it possible to see if two MP3 files are the same song by analyzing the files' bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482906/is-it-possible-to-see-if-two-mp3-files-are-the-same-song-by-analyzing-the-files)

[Java: Comparing two audio files to see if they are the same "music"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988052/java-comparing-two-audio-files-to-see-if-they-are-the-same-music)

You might also look into the [echonest API](http://echonest.com/) and [echoprint](http://echoprint.me/).